# Classic references on equation solving.

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If I'm correct, old style algebra books ( before 1945)  concentrated on equation solving, and modern ones concentrate more on functions and their graphs ( as a preparation to calculus).

Are there classical references, popular amongst math students / teachers - not too old references ( I'd better like not before mid 40's, for fear terminology might be out of date ) - concentrating specially on equation solving ( at the intermediate level).

I once saw a post dealing vith absolute value expressions as exponents with an example taken  from Dorofeev's  Elementary mathematics. That kind of reference ( with that kind of exercise)  would be of great interest to me.   ( Unfortunately it is rather difficult to find a copy of Dorofeev's book).

Remark. When I say " not too old ones", don't understand I have prejudices against old math books. To the contrary I highly appreciate math books written during the period 1945-1970 first for typography , second for clarity and elegance in explanations, third for a certain " free thinking air" ( so to say) one can breathe in these books. As an example, I'd take Moses Richardon's books.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you need something quick, one of the best handbooks is "Mathematical handbook for scientists and engineers" by G.A. Korn and T.M. Korn.

Comment: Thanks for this reference.  Andrey, do you know any book comparable to Dorofeev's Elementary mathematics ?

Comment: Unfortunately, no, but I think, any Elementary mathematics book of the stated years  would be as well good.